# VBA code to shift columns over and maintain formula

Tags: vba, excel

Hi guys so this is my code:

```
Sub Biz1_Shift_OnePeriod()
    'Shift all values one period to the left

    'Message Box Question
    Ans = MsgBox("Update data by one year?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Data Update")
    If Ans = vbNo Then Exit Sub


    'Turn off screen updating & calculation to make code run faster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim CopyFromWks As Worksheet
    Dim CopyToWks As Worksheet
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim C As Range


    '---------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Business - Balance Sheet
    '
    '
    'Set the worksheet
    Sheets("Balance Sheet").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Set CopyToWks = Sheets("Balance Sheet")
    Set CopyFromWks = Sheets("Balance Sheet")
    '
    'Copy data loop from 2nd Historical to 3rd Historical
    Set Copyfrom = CopyFromWks.Range("L:L")
    Set Copyto = CopyToWks.Range("I:I")
    For i = 1 To 1
        For j = 1 To 95
            For Each C In Copyfrom.Cells(j, i)
                If C.Locked = False Then
                    Copyto(j, i).Value = Copyfrom(j, i).Value
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
    '
    'Copy data loop from 1st Historical to 2nd Historical
    Set Copyfrom = CopyFromWks.Range("O:O")
    Set Copyto = CopyToWks.Range("L:L")
    For i = 1 To 1
        For j = 1 To 95
            For Each C In Copyfrom.Cells(j, i)
                If C.Locked = False Then
                    Copyto(j, i).Value = Copyfrom(j, i).Value
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
    '
    'Set Historical Yr 1 to Zero
    Set Copyto = CopyToWks.Range("O:O")
    For i = 1 To 1
        For j = 1 To 95
            For Each C In Copyfrom.Cells(j, i)
                If C.Locked = False Then
                    Copyto(j, i).Value = 0
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
    '
    'Set Current equal to Zero
    Set Copyto = CopyToWks.Range("R:R")
    For i = 1 To 1
        For j = 1 To 95
            For Each C In Copyto.Cells(j, i)
                If C.Locked = False Then
                    Copyto(j, i).Value = 0
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

What I want to do is shift my columns over to the left.  I thought a copy paste method would do and for now I have the last column set to 0.  However, I need the last column to retain all its formulas, but have it not be pulling from any data source.  I came up with an idea to create another column that would be hidden and storing all the formula there and have that shift over when the macro is triggered.  I wanted to ask you guys if there is a better way of going about this and help brainstorm a little bit.

Comment: What are your formulas like?

Comment: @user3598756 My formulas are like this: 

=IFERROR(IF(P$4="1120S",INDEX(B1HY1!$A$3:$F$300,MATCH(20,B1HY1!$F$3:$F$300,0),5)+INDEX(B1HY1!$A$3:$F$300,MATCH("K 12a",B1HY1!$F$3:$F$300,0),5),IF(P$4=1120,INDEX(B1HY1!$A$3:$F$300,MATCH(27,B1HY1!$F$3:$F$300,0),5),IF(P$4=1065,INDEX(B1HY1!$A$3:$F$300,MATCH(21,B1HY1!$F$3:$F$300,0),5),0))),0)

Comment: did you try @MakPo solution?

Comment: @user3598756 
I am testing it out now.  I will get back to you if it works.

Comment: if it works get back to him and mark his answer as accepted!

Comment: @user3598756 I definitely Will!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```